# Is there any way to set 'varchar' in number type?

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

When I write:

```
SELECT 
    last_name, NVL(commission_pct, 0)
FROM 
    Hr.employees;
```

it works fine. When commission percentage is null, then it is set to 0.

But I want to set it to 'NO COMMISSION' instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try coalesce function. COALESCE is ANSI standard.

```sql
select last_name, COALESCE(to_char(commission_pct),'NO COMMISSION')
from hr.employees
```

Answer (score 2):

If you return the commision value as a string, yes.

```
select last_name, nvl(to_char(commission_pct),'NO COMMISSION')
from hr.employees
```